# Ionic Angular doesnt upload files for web version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i am building a cross platform app and i am using Ionic 3 Angular 5. I made an upload process script in .ts file it works fine on ios and android but it doesnt work on desktop version. What should i do?

```
      chooseImage()
       actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        title: 'Select Image Source',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Load from Gallery',
                handler: () => {
                    let options = {
                        sourceType: 2,
                        encodingType: 0,
                        destinationType: 0,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        quality: 95,
                        targetWidth: 800,
                        targetHeight: 600,
                        correctOrientation: true
                    };

                    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(uri => {
                        this.image_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + uri;
                    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Use Camera',
                handler: () => {
                    let options = {
                        sourceType: 1,
                        encodingType: 0,
                        destinationType: 0,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        quality: 95,
                        targetWidth: 800,
                        targetHeight: 600,
                        correctOrientation: true
                    };

                    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(uri => {
                        this.image_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + uri;
                    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel'
            }
        ]
        });
        actionSheet.present();
         }


        <button round ion-button full color="picture" style="margin:auto;padding:10px;
            display:block;" (click)="chooseImage()">
                Select a Photo
            </button>
```

WhAT SHOULD I DO?

Comment: Is there anyway i can do that with ionic cordova run browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a desktop app from your ionic code while using all the ionic native plugins, then you need to use **Electron** as per Ionic Documentation. While I don't have an experience on the Electron-Ionic integration, you can refer on the sample below to get it started.

I hope the links below can help you.

See link below:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/desktop-app

Sample:
https://medium.com/@LohaniDamodar/lets-make-desktop-application-with-ionic-3-and-electron-44316f82901d

You can also try checking Capacitor for Ionic:
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/